# Undo changes of JSENCODE() when used in output text

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, pdf, renderas

I have VF page in which i have a output text like the below one.

```
<apex:outputText value=" {!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(title),'\n','<br/>')}" escape="false"/>
```

Lets say the value of the `title` attribute is `"Demo car's result"`.

when i print this page or render it as PDF, the value displays as `"Demo car\'s result"`.

I want to Js encode the attribute but when rendering as pdf i don't want this backslash to be displayed.

Please let me know if there is a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want only the `input` which would be passed to apex controller to be `JSENCODE`. But you are doing `output`, so you dont really need `JSENCODE` - without it, the rendering will be done properly.

```
<apex:outputText value=" {!SUBSTITUTE(title,'\n','<br/>')}" escape="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.